# SQLite no such column from right side of nested inner join

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables in a  SQLite DB, Task, Project, and User, all associated with one another in that order. I would like to select ALL Tasks, and if the Project the Task is associated with has a User I would like to see both the User and the Project, otherwise I do not want the Project at all.

My first pass looked like

```
SELECT `Task`.`id`
    ,`Task`.`title`
    ,`Task`.`projectId`
    ,`Project`.`id` AS `Project.id`
    ,`Project`.`title` AS `Project.title`
    ,`Project`.`userId` AS `Project.userId`
    ,`Project.User`.`id` AS `Project.user.id`
    ,`Project.User`.`username` AS `Project.User.username`
FROM `Task` AS `Task` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `Project` AS `Project` ON `Task`.`projectId` = `project`.`id`
INNER JOIN `User` AS `Project.User` ON `Project`.`userId` = `Project.User`.`id`
AND `Project.User`.`username` = 'test01';
```

but the inner join "rippled" back up and I only got Tasks that had a Project with a User. Since I wanted to get all Tasks, I added some parenthesis and got

```
SELECT `Task`.`id`
    ,`Task`.`title`
    ,`Task`.`projectId`
    ,`Project`.`id` AS `Project.id`
    ,`Project`.`title` AS `Project.title`
    ,`Project`.`userId` AS `Project.userId`
    ,`Project.User`.`id` AS `Project.user.id`
    ,`Project.User`.`username` AS `Project.User.username`
FROM `Task` AS `Task`
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (`Project` AS `Project` 
INNER JOIN `User` AS `Project.User` ON `Project`.`userId` = `Project.User`.`id`
    AND `Project.User`.`username` = 'test01' ) ON `Task`.`projectId` = `project`.`id`;
```

This works great if I omit the `Project.User` columns from the SELECT, but I want them as well. When I run this as is I get the following error

```
no such column: Project.User.id
```

It seems that adding the parentheses has in some way hidden the User table. Is there a way to get all the behavior I want from this statement?

Comment: And you do have the column `id` in the `User` table? Try changing `Project.User` to something like `Project_User` and see if the problem persists, I am not sure if this might be the case of `.` operator being understood differently in `SQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ishmaelMakitla is right. By simply changing the name of the alias it all works

```
SELECT `Task`.`id`
    ,`Task`.`title`
    ,`Task`.`projectId`
    ,`Project`.`id` AS `Project.id`
    ,`Project`.`title` AS `Project.title`
    ,`Project`.`userId` AS `Project_UserId`
    ,`Project_User`.`id` AS `Project_User.id`
    ,`Project_User`.`username` AS `Project_User.username`
FROM `Task` AS `Task`
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (`Project` AS `Project` 
INNER JOIN `User` AS `Project_User` ON `Project`.`userId` = `Project_User`.`id`
    AND `Project_User`.`username` = 'test01' ) ON `Task`.`projectId` = `project`.`id`;
```